# Silverlight occasionally fails to start my app

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight-4.0

I have noticed that on occasion Internet Explorer running Silverlight 4 fails to start my app.  Hitting F5 fixes this problem, but I would expect an error or other problem to show itself during these failures.  Has anyone had similar problems and what was the resolution?  I am using Application Library Caching.  Unfortunately I have not found a way to reproduce the problem;  I can only sit back and expect to occur on occasion.  I have seen this same problem occur with other apps we have deployed, though they do not share any code base.

Comment: Are you certain an uncaught exception is not propagating out under a certain condition?

Comment: Yes.  I have very good handlers in place inside and outside of the browser.  I am trying to trace it through Fiddler but have not been lucky enough as of yet to pick it up with Fiddler running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe experiencing a race condition when rendering the page. If you're using the object tag, then try using Silverlight.js to load the application after the page has loaded.

If it doesn't help, then remove any splash.xaml / javascript logic and load the application clean with the standard loading screen. If this solution helps, then there's something wrong with your splash screen.

Give these two a try.